# Get arrays from Csv file to plot a chart

Tags: python

I have this Csv file:

```
DateTime;S1;S2;S3
2020-07-15 16:27:01.221660;652.3826361765446;661.0531016851814;387.24703877989487
2020-07-15 16:27:01.221660;953.4271004457892;873.8955069132078;397.91143086810587
```

I want to read the file by columns, so:

```
DateTime_array = [2020-07-15 16:27:01.221660,2020-07-15 16:27:01.221660]
S1_array = [652.3826361765446,953.4271004457892]
S2_array = [661.0531016851814,873.8955069132078]
S3_array = [387.24703877989487,397.91143086810587]
```

After this I want to plot data, `DateTime_array` is the X coordinates for each Signal(S1,S2...) and in Signals array are contained the Y coordinates.

How can I do this?
Is there any other way to do it straight from the csv?

Comment: You might need to have a look into [`pandas.read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python's [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/index.html) package is most convenient way to deal with data, including .csv files.
You can easily read from you csv:

```
import pandas as pd
my_df = pd.read_csv(path, parse_dates=True)
```

(some adaptations may needed, as .csv has several formats. But this is right method to call)

Now you have a dataframe object looks exactly like your .csv file. It is easy to manipulate data. For example, if you just want to plot one column:

```
my_df.plot.scatter(x='DataTime', y='S1')
```

If you want a more complex plot you should use matplotlib package directly.

And if all you want is to save your data as an array:

```py
DateTime_array = my_df["DataTime"].tolist()
S1_array = my_df["S1"].tolist()
```

As I said, when dealing with data - pandas' DataFrame object is the right way to manipulate data, so no need to extract values to arrays.

Comment: The `parse_dates` flag of pandas `read_csv` does not parse datetime properly. A custom parser should be seperately provided to it.

Comment: My minor experience with `parse_dates` was absolutely fine. Thank you for this comment, I'm glad it's here if someone get stuck because of that flag

Answer (score 1):

You can use Python's Pandas to solve your problem. This is what you need:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv(csv_file_path, sep=";")
df["DateTime"] = pd.to_datetime(df["DateTime"]) 
df.set_index("DateTime").plot()
```